# remove � question mark characters from columns

Tags: r, utf

I have a dataset in which some row values have � (question mark). How can I remove these? This symbol however for some reason does not show up in MS-Excel (so maybe � is space?).

[image]

Please note I am new to this kind of special character, so I don't know how to create a sample dataset with �.

However, this is how some of the values look like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: unicode or utf-8/-16?

Comment: @r2evans, yeah maybe, as I found something similar here [White Question Mark in Black Diamond](https://superuser.com/questions/316752/white-question-mark-in-black-diamond).

Comment: You can typically get rid of multibyte Unicode sequences using e.g. `sub('\\X', '', df$requestor_name, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @AllanCameron, thank you, however this returns an error `Error in sub("\\X", "", df_final$requestor_name, perl = TRUE) : 
  input string 6019 is invalid UTF-8`